# Installing pip for python3.3

Tags: python, macos, unix, pip, python-3.3

I downloaded pip from [Package Index > pip 1.2.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)

Then I installed it using

```
sudo python3.3 setup.py install
```

Still, when I try to use `pip-3.3` the terminal complains

```
-bash: pip-3.3: command not found
```

However, `pip-2.7` works swimmingly.

I have also tried

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo python3.3 distribute_setup.py
sudo python3.3 -m easy_install pip
```

But `pip-3.3` still does not work.

What do I do to install pip for Python 3.3?

Note that there is a related thread [How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3), but the answer is  just "Install distribute ... and then use that to install pip" which is not helpful to me because I have tried it and it did not work.

Comment: for me `pip-2.6` is installed in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pip-2.6`.  It seems logical that `pip-3.3` could be "installed", just not somewhere on `PATH`

Comment: To other newbs: I had to add *PATH="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH"* to my .bash_profile file.

Comment: @mgilson *Blushing* Sorry, I'm a rank newb. Please post your answer and I will accept it. Might be other *nix igoramuses wondering about the same thing

Comment: No problem.  It was a reasonable question -- And really I've never had any problem like this on Linux.  (On Linux, my python installations always go to a reasonable location -- I'm not sure why they seem to end up in strange places on OS-X/Darwin machines).

Comment: @TheUnfunCat - did you install Python3.3 by Macports  that is the only reason I know of that needs /opt/local/bin on the path? If so the install pip as a port

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Chances are that `pip` did get installed successfully *somewhere*.  However, *somewhere* is probably not on your `PATH` and so you shell (bash) doesn't know where to find it.  For me, `pip-2.6` is installed in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/
```

It is probably a similar path for you (only 3.3 instead of 2.6).  Of course, adding to `PATH` is shell dependent.  On bash-like shells you'd use `export` and on csh-like shells you'd use `setenv` -- And for convenience, you'd probably want to make the change in your shell's initialization file (e.g `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or something similar).

Answer (score 5):

One way to go is to use the homebrew install for python3. It comes with pip3 builtin. It also means you have an uninstaller unlike the dmg/pkg install.

If you have homebrew already its as easy as `brew install python3`. More detailed instructions [here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/02/04/how-to-install-python-3-and-pydev-on-osx#2). And you can read more about the python3 brew install [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python).

Answer (score 1):

**For Mac:**

```
sudo easy_install pip3
```

If you still run into trouble, possibly because you compiled python3 yourself, use apt-get or homebrew to uninstall your compilation and reinstall the python3 package, at which point it should come with pip.

```
brew uninstall python3
brew install python3
brew link --overwrite python3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3.3
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17601159/819417).

Answer (score 0):

*If* pip is actually installed, it can always be invoked via the versioned Python command like this:

```
python3.3 -m pip
```