# How to install pip for python3.3 alongside default python

Tags: pip, python-3.3

I downloaded and installed `python3.3` from the [website](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-337/) and followed the instructions in the readme file.

I can run `python3.3` from commandline, but when I try to install a package with pip, it will install to the default python (Anaconda python 3.6 in my case).

I tried installing a new pip using `easy_install` as described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183112/installing-pip-for-python3-3), but it gives me the error saying

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.3: No module named easy_install
```

**How can I install the setuptools if I don't have pip?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the virtualenv from anaconda directly as described [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html).

```
conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda
```

This will also setup pip, so installation of new packages is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Anaconda distribution (Python 3.6) have pip installed already? If yes, you can use virtualenv as virtual environment.

1. Check if you have virtualenv installed. In my computer, I have virtualenv 16.0.0 installed.

   ```
   $ virtualenv --version
   16.0.0
   ```

   If it says, "command not found", you can install virtualenv.

   ```
   $ pip3 install virtualenv
   ```
2. Once virtualenv is installed, create a new virtual environment, with Python 3.3. 
   In the command below, we will create a new virtual environment called venv, that uses Python 3.3.

   ```
   $ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.3 <path/to/new/virtualenv/> venv
   ```

   If it says the path does not exist, check the path to python 3.3 using which   command.

   ```
   $ which python3.3
   ```
3. Activate the the virtual environment venv. The commands are `activate` to activate and `deactivate` to deactivate.

   ```
   $ source venv/bin/activate
   ```
4. Install the package that you want.

   ```
   $ pip3 install X
   ```
5. Once you are done and what to use the default Python 3.6, `deactivate` the virtual environment.

@aeduG's answer is correct. Alternatively, you can use virtualenv. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398676/does-conda-replace-the-need-for-virtualenv) for the differences between conda virtual environment and virtualenv.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174935/conda-creating-a-virtual-environment) if you want to use conda's virtual environment instead.