# Error installing Dynamic-DynamoDB using pip

Tags: python, linux, pip

I am completely newbie to Python and just trying to install [Dynamic-DynamoDB](http://sebdah.github.io/dynamic-dynamodb/) python package on RHEL5 Linux for very first time. I didn't have pip on my system so I followed instructions as in asnwer to [What is the official "preferred" way to install pip and virtualenv systemwide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585875/what-is-the-official-preferred-way-to-install-pip-and-virtualenv-systemwide)

Now when I try to install dynamic-dynamoDB as mentioned in installing instructions, it gives me error.

```
pip install dynamic-dynamodb
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin//pip", line 8, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 345, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2381, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2087, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in ?
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in ?
    from pip.download import path_to_url2
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 3, in ?
    import hashlib
ImportError: No module named hashlib
```

Any suggestions on what am I missing here?

Comment: from other questions, it seems, this module is missing from python versions less than 2.4. I will try reinstalling newer version

Comment: okay I updated my version to 2.7 and error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Dynamic-DynamoDB. Sorry for a late answer, I wanted to answer anyway in case anyone else has the same problem later on.

The reason is that the Python version is too old. Dynamic DynamoDB supports Python >2.6.