# How to upgrade pip3?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to use python3.5 for development, but many times when I install the module for python 3.5, it always fails. The terminal tells me that a higher version is available, but it doesn't work when I upgrade it.
[image]

Comment: You missed out a `3` in your second command

Comment: Unluckily,it not work neither pip3 install --upgrade pip not pip install --upgrade pip3.

Comment: Could you post the new error message for `pip3`?

Comment: I try again,it works,thank you!

Comment: Doesnt work for pip3

Answer (score 145):

You are using pip3 to install flask-script which is associated with python 3.5. However, you are trying to upgrade pip associated with the python 2.7, try running `pip3 install --upgrade pip`.

It might be a good idea to take some time and read about virtual environments in Python. It isn't a best practice to install all of your packages to the base python installation. This would be a good start: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade pip will only upgrade pip for python2 not pip3.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle no it won't, I just tested it.. (but i tested it while being in the pip3 local directory)

Comment: I just tested this *not* in the pip3 local directory and it updated pip3 but didn't touch pip (aka pip2)

Answer (score 109):

To upgrade your pip3, try running:

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Your pip may move from `/bin` to `/usr/local/bin`

To upgrade pip as well, you can follow it by:

```
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly, whilst all other pip3 install --user --upgrade pip/pip3 failed. Thanks.

Comment: this messed up my pip (for python 2)

Comment: wrong, pip3 install --upgrade pip will only install the upgrade for pip, not pip3.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle no it won't, I just tested it.. (but i tested it while being in the pip3 local directory, i don't know if it makes a difference, just wanted to be sure)

Comment: `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` worked for me on amazon linux 2 but it changed the location of the binary. I updated the answer.

Comment: You need to be very careful when using `sudo` with pip. See [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip)

Answer (score 41):

Try this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

Comment: My windows 10 command line suggested `c:\python3\python3.exe -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`

Comment: Works for mac, which python3 was installed from .dmg file.

Comment: screwed up my pip3 on ubuntu16

Comment: `sudo python3 -m pip uninstall pip && sudo apt install python3-pip --reinstall` solved the ImportError problem for me. Environment is ubuntu 18.04, it happened when I tried to upgrade pip3 (9 -> 19) on python 3.6. The snippet is from [Anthony Sottile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836753/8626681)

Comment: This just worked for me and this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 30):

First decide which pip you want to upgrade, i.e. just pip or pip3.
Mostly it'll be pip3 because pip is used by the system, so I won't recommend upgrading pip.

The difference between pip and pip3 is that

> NOTE: I'm referring to PIP that is at the BEGINNING of the command
> line.

> pip is used by python version 2, i.e. python2

and

> pip3 is used by python version 3, i.e. python3

For upgrading pip3: # This will upgrade python3 pip.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

For upgrading pip: # This will upgrade python2 pip.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

This will upgrade your existing pip to the latest version.

Comment: wrong, pip3 install --upgrade pip will only install the upgrade for pip, not pip3.

Comment: Mac ships with python v2.7, but most of the developers tend to use Python v3.x, So pip3 is explicitly used to upgrade python3 package manager, and not python2 i.e shipped by Mac.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46424582/8972021 Martin has also explained here.

Answer (score 19):

### The Problem

You use `pip` (the Python 2 one). Now you want to upgrade `pip` (the Python 3 one). After that, `pip` is the Python 3 one.

### The solution

Use `pip2` and `pip3`. This way it is explicit.

If you want to use `pip`, just check where it is (`which pip`) and change the link. For example:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)

$ which pip2
/usr/local/bin/pip2

$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip2 /usr/local/bin/pip

$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Answer (score 19):

- for Python 3:

  ```
  python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
  ```
- for Python 2:

  ```
  python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip
  ```

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 6):

`pip3 install --upgrade pip` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04, below are the steps that I followed.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

For some reason you will be getting an error, and that be fixed by making bash forget the wrongly referenced locations using the following command.

```
hash -r pip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 versions of Python (eg: 2.7.x and 3.6), you need do:

1. **add the path of 2.x to system PATH**
2. **add the path of 3.x to system PATH**
3. `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

for example, in my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin:$PATH
```

You can exec command `pip --version` and `pip3 --version` check the pip from the special version. Because if don't add Python path to $PATH, and exec `pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`, your pip will be changed to pip from python3, but the pip should from python2.x

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (mac)

```
sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip3
```

you will get the following error:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

but if you upgrade using the suggested command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then, the legacy pip will be upgraded, so what I did is the following:

```
which pip3
```

and I located my pip3 installation (just in case the following command wouldn't upgrade the legacy pip. Then i changed to that directory and upgraded pip3 using the following commands: (your directory could be different)

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

after this:

```
pip --version
```

will still show the legacy version, while

```
pip3 --version
```

will show pip 21.0.1