# Install Pandas on Mac with pip

Tags: python, macos, pandas, pip

I am trying to install `Pandas` with `pip`, but ran into to a problem. Here are the details:

```
Mac OS Sierra
which python => /usr/bin/python
python --version => Python 2.7.10
Inside "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions" there is the following
2.3 2.5 2.6 2.7 Current
```

**I want pandas to be linked to `Python 2.7.10` in "/usr/bin/python"**

When I do `pip install pandas`, I get the following error message:

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-0.19.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl

Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)

Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)

Installing collected packages: pandas

Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-
py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas'
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try running it as sudo. sudo pip install pandas

Comment: @abccd, you are right

Comment: @bdeo, that worked :-)

can you please explain why it worked? thanks, just so that I have some sense of what is going on,

Comment: In order to create files (the pandas package) in the directory they need to be in, you need to be a super user of the system because they live in the systems files, not in your users files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try running the pip install command as sudo.

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

Python packages are installed in the operating systems file system where not all users have permission to write files to. This is why you need to run the command as sudo, as sudo elevates your privileges to do this.

Edit: This seems to be getting some upvotes so I've added some clarity to this question regarding user specific installation. You can also install this just for your user should this fit your use case with: `pip install --user pandas`.

Answer (score 6):

for mac terminal using mojave works with

```
pip3 install pandas
```

or

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

after

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: Done, shaying requirement alreay satisfied. But, after import it showing errror , ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Answer (score 4):

`pip3 install pandas` instead of `pip install pandas` should do the trick if you are on Python 3.0

Answer (score 2):

running **pip3 install pandas** on the Terminal window worked for me on a MAC OS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, running with `sudo` should solve the problem. Although its [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip). You can also do: 

`pip install --user <packagename>`

Also, I highly recommended using [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) to manage python versions for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers I had to account for some compiler specific issues on MacOS using

```
sudo CFLAGS='-Wno-implicit-function-declaration' pip3 install pandas
```