# Install pandas on linux, only using a python file

Tags: python, linux

I am required to install pandas using the .py file using the linux command line, before importing pandas once it is installed.
If anyone knows how to also do this on macOS that would be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Pandas on Mac with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616376/install-pandas-on-mac-with-pip)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Python packages from local file system folder to virtualenv with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031694/installing-python-packages-from-local-file-system-folder-to-virtualenv-with-pip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like:

```
import os
cmd = 'sudo pip install pandas'
os.system(cmd)
```

based on: https://cmdlinetips.com/2014/03/how-to-run-a-shell-command-from-python-and-get-the-output/

Comment: I believe it should work. Just install pip using     sudo easy_install pip