# aws CLI unable to be used due to module colorama

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, colorama

aI've installed AWS CLI and am trying to use it on Mac OS Sierra. It complains there is is no module `colorama`:

> $ aws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from awscli.formatter import get_formatter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/awscli/formatter.py", line 19, in <module>
    from awscli.table import MultiTable, Styler, ColorizedStyler
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/awscli/table.py", line 18, in <module>
    import colorama
ImportError: No module named colorama
```

So I try to install it and it says the requirement is already satisfied:

> $ sudo pip install colorama

```
The directory '/Users/danniu/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/danniu/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in /Users/danniu/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't install Python modules with `sudo`. If you add the `--user` command line option, this will install the package into your home folder (which your user owns) and you won't need to use `sudo`.

If you want this to be default, you can create a `pip.conf` file with the following contents:

```
[install]
user = true
```

located where it should on your given operating system (on macOS Sierra it's located at `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf`).

The easiest solution to your problem is to run

```
$ pip install --upgrade --user awscli
```

as this will make sure you have all needed dependencies.

Comment: Couldn't I just do `ln -s /Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/awscli/site-packages` and symlink?

Comment: Maybe, but the modules would still be owned by root and things are starting to get messy/disorganized.

Comment: See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip
The discussion in the comments is enlightening too.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced this issue on MacOS Sierra and below command solved the issue.

`pip install --ignore-installed six --upgrade --user awscli`

Read more about why to use `--ignore-installed six` on github issue raised for **installing the awscli on mac**. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165.

Also read AWS Doc on how to install AWS CLI :- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html