# I am trying to install ipython but get permission error

Tags: python, ipython, python-3.5

I use command pip3 install ipython
but getting these error 
may I need to install virtualenv ?

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/saurabh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython'
```

Comment: Please add `sudo`: `sudo pip3 install IPython`

Comment: NO! Do **NOT** use `sudo` with `pip`. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I am actually surprised to hear such a thing from you. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip)

Comment: it works thanks @COLDSPEED

Comment: Sudo pip is a very dangerous game to play. There are much safer ways around this issue that would have come up in a simple Google search.

Comment: @mentalita relax, it was for IPython, pretty trustworthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message reveals the problem: You don't have permission to write to the folder since `/usr/...` is a system folder.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython'
```

You need to use `sudo` to install globally or just install them using `--user` option which installs the package only for the current user and not for all:

```
pip install ipython --user
```

---

Or maybe a better option is to use a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) which isolates packages for you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever any permission issues/error are there during installation of any package always add `sudo` before your installation command. Hence command will be:

```
sudo pip3 install IPython
```