# ImportError: No module named 'cloudant.client'; 'cloudant' is not a package

Tags: python, cloudant, python-cloudant

I use Python 3.5 and I have installed cloudant package by an execute command:

```
sudo -H pip3 install cloudant
```

I try to connect with python database. According to the documentation - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/getting-started.html#getting-started-with-cloudant. This code should works:

```
from cloudant.client import Cloudant

client = Cloudant("username", "password", url="https://user_name.cloudant.com")
client.connect()
client.disconnect()
```

When I run it I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/tomek/Projects/stage-control/cloudant.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cloudant.client import Cloudant
ImportError: No module named 'cloudant.client'; 'cloudant' is not a package
```

Comment: Type `pip show cloudant` on the command line. What is reported? If nothing, then the package isn't installed. Also, you rarely want to install packages with `sudo`. Just do it as your normal user. See [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your problem may be that the `pip` used to install the module isn't the `pip` that your python is using:

If I do `pip3 install cloudant` I get the same problem as you:

```
(py35) stefans-mbp:work stefan$ python
Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Mar  6 2017, 12:15:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cloudant.client import Cloudant
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cloudant.client'
```

This is because of this:

```
(py35) stefans-mbp:work stefan$ which pip
//anaconda/envs/py35/bin/pip
(py35) stefans-mbp:work stefan$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

The wrong `pip3` was used to install the `cloudant` module. To remedy, ensure you use the `pip` in the virtual env you're using:

```
(py35) stefans-mbp:work stefan$ pip install cloudant
Collecting cloudant
Using cached cloudant-2.7.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.7.0 in 
/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from cloudant)
Building wheels for collected packages: cloudant
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cloudant ... done
  Stored in directory: ...
Successfully built cloudant
Installing collected packages: cloudant
Successfully installed cloudant-2.7.0
```

Now it works:

```
(py35) stefans-mbp:work stefan$ python
Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Mar  6 2017, 12:15:08) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cloudant.client import Cloudant
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just rename your file `cloudant.py` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running locally or in an app on Bluemix? There must be something wrong with your install, because the code looks fine. This code runs for me:

```
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
from cloudant.document import Document

client = Cloudant("username", "pw", url="https://username.cloudant.com")
client.connect()
thedb = client["databasename"]
for document in thedb:
    print(document)
client.disconnect()
```

If you're running on Bluemix, make sure you have a `requirements.txt` file to trigger library imports. See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html