# I'm having some trouble using IBM cloud cloudant , any help would be greatly appreciated

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

here's my code
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
from cloudant.error import CloudantException
def main(param_dict):

```
try:
    client = Cloudant.iam(
        account_name=param_dict[USERNAME],
        api_key=param_dict[APIKEY],
        connect=True,
    )
    print(f"Databases: {client.all_dbs()}")
except CloudantException as cloudant_exception:
    print("unable to connect")
    return {"error": cloudant_exception}
except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ConnectionResetError) as err:
    print("connection error")
    return {"error": err}

return {"dbs": client.all_dbs()}
```

I'm getting this error :

Logs:

```
[
  "2023-04-05T15:04:17.941831Z    stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):",
  "2023-04-05T15:04:17.942135Z    stderr: File \"/action/1/bin/exec__.py\", line 44, in <module>",
  "2023-04-05T15:04:17.944270Z    stderr: from main__ import main as main",
  "2023-04-05T15:04:17.944503Z    stderr: File \"/action/1/bin/main__.py\", line 1, in <module>",
  "2023-04-05T15:04:17.944939Z    stderr: from cloudant.client import Cloudant",
  "2023-04-05T15:04:17.945205Z    stderr: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cloudant'",
  "2023-04-05T15:04:17.958247Z    stderr: Command exited abruptly during initialization.",
  "2023-04-05T15:04:17.958Z       stderr: The action did not initialize or run as expected. Log data might be missing."
]
```

I'm using cloudant on ibm cloud platform.

Comment: That's a problem with your environment. Have you installed the required module?

Comment: the environment is ibm cloud

Comment: The environment is where you code runs. It needs to have the required modules / packages. YOU have to configure that.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have Cloudant module installed in your Python application. Check this answer for additional hints - [ImportError: No module named 'cloudant.client'; 'cloudant' is not a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040754/importerror-no-module-named-cloudant-client-cloudant-is-not-a-package)

How do you build and run your application?