# I'm not able to install PIL. Terminal says access denied to directory. How to gain access to the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, easy-install

I typed in this command in the terminal

```
easy_install PIL
```

The terminal said this:

```
    *error: can't create or remove files in install directory
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-639.pth'
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.
For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:
  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html
Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.*
```

How should I continue?

Comment: Did you even google your problem before asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Said, you were trying to install PIL  but `easy_install PI` command was not going to install it, you're typed it wrong.
Though in my opinion you can try this

`pip install --user Pillow`

[Additional

Why You Should not Use sudo while install Python Libs?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21056000/7917825. ]

Comment: I did as u said.
terminal says this:

Ganeshs-MacBook-Air:~ vishveshbhat$ pip install --user Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

But now when i type " from PIL import Image" into IDLE python shell, i get this:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

What should I do?

Comment: Uninstall pillow then Install it again

Answer (score 1):

Try adding sudo before easy_install

```
sudo easy_install Pillow
```