# Why won't pip install django 2.x?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

Pip will not let me install django 2.0.7. When I execute `sudo -H pip install Django==2.0.7` it says:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.0.7 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14)

No matching distribution found for Django==2.0.7
```

As you can see above, the most recent version it can find is version `1.11.14`. Normally, I would be okay with downloading that but it is not compatible with Python 3.7 (the version I have). I have also checked to make sure `pip` was updated to the latest version (`pip 10.0.1`).

Comment: You are installing Django for the intergrated Python 2.7.  Try `pythonXX -m pip install django`

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the help! Can you write you comment as an answer so I can approve it as answered?

Comment: @PaulSpringer  Sure give me a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac and Linux (and similar systems) both contain default installations (generally Python 2.7).  This is accessed via `python` in terminal.

`pip` if installed will also be for Python 2.7 (or whatever it is on your system).

When you run `sudo -H pip install Django==2.0.7` it points to the 2.7 installation (or your equivalent).

You can test this via the `which pip` command, which will show in the path where it is installing to.

As mentioned in the other answer, Django lost support for 2.7 with version `1.11.14` so you cannot install the version 2 Django since it has no support (this is your error) for Python 2.

**Now to deal with the problem:**

To install Django you just need to tell the terminal which interpreter to use.  As mentioned you could use `pip37` or I prefer to use:

```
python37 -m pip install Django
```

Simply because I use `python37` command all the time so I know it will work, and will therefore install to the correct location.

---

Note that since you are installing Django you should probably be using a separate environment for security ([venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)).

[The `sudo` should not be used only as an absolute last resort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/6622817) (as already mentioned by [abccd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622817/abccd)) as it can ruin your system (I have done this multiple times in a Virtual Installation, so it is definitly something you want to avoid if possible), once again using a virtual environment would ensure that you do not need the `sudo` command since you are not installing in a root dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

As Simon has mentioned in the comments: your `sudo -H pip` is installing for Python 2.7, which explains why the latest version for Django is 1.11.14 since Django 2.x dropped support for Python 2.7.

You'll need to use Python 3.7's `pip`, run either one of the following:

```
pip3 install --user django
python37 install --user django
python3 install --user django 
pip37 install --user django
```

[You REALLY shouldn't use `pip` with `sudo` (it's not safe).](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/6622817)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to above answers, if you are using a virtual environment, make sure you are using Python3 to create it. You can explicitly do that like this :

```
virtualenv -p C:\Python36\python3.exe VE_Project
```

Activate the env . Now if you do a **"pip install Django"** , it will install the latest in 2.x series.