# Error while drawing a graph in networkx .module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ishold'

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

I want to plot a graph using networkx. But module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ishold' error is coming. I have tried using the earlier versions of matplotlib but it didn't work. Yesterday, the same code was running but now it is showing this error. Please help. Im stuck.

I have tried using the earlier versions of matplotlib but it didn't work. Yesterday, the same code was running but now it is showing this error. Please help. Im stuck.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(
    [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('E', 'C'), ('E', 'F'),
     ('B', 'H'), ('B', 'G'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'G')])

val_map = {'A': 1.0,
           'D': 0.5714285714285714,
           'H': 0.0}

values = [val_map.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]
%matplotlib inline 
nx.draw_networkx(G, cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_color = values)

nx.draw(G)
plt.show()

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-127734f4f34b> in <module>()
     14 values = [val_map.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]
     15 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib inline')
---> 16 nx.draw_networkx(G, cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_color = values)
     17 
     18 nx.draw(G)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py in draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist, width, edge_color, style, alpha, edge_cmap, edge_vmin, edge_vmax, ax, arrows, label, **kwds)
    520         lw = width
    521 
--> 522     if not cb.is_string_like(edge_color) \
    523            and cb.iterable(edge_color) \
    524            and len(edge_color) == len(edge_pos):

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'is_string_like'
```

[image]

Comment: The error shown is a totally different one than the one reported in the title. Which one do you want to inquire about? What are the versions of the libraries in use?

Comment: My code worked for matplotlib version 2.2.3 . In other versions, it was either showing 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ishold' or the error that I mentioned in my code. Thank you anyways!

Comment: So your networkx version is not compatible with your matplotlib version. That's all one can say.

Comment: yeah.. I figured that later. But it seems the recent version of matplotlib does not support nx.draw functionality.

Comment: networkx is not a dependency of matplotlib, but rather matplotlib is a dependency of networkx. So if anything, networkx might be broken.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it's due to a mismatch in the versions of networkx and matplotlib. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the packages - it worked!

```
sudo pip3 uninstall networkx

sudo pip3 uninstall matplotlib

python3 -mpip uninstall matplotlib

sudo conda uninstall matplotlib
```

If you've installed networkx via other sources like mpip or conda, uninstall via those too.

Then install both of them:

```
sudo pip3 install networkx

sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

Comment: you should not be using sudo with pip https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/4996681

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded matplotlib version to 2.2.3 and it works.

just input

pip install matplotlib==2.2.3.

hope it helps~

Comment: yup. it did! Thanks