# How can I install pygame to my vs code project in OSX?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pygame

I want to add pygame package to my vs code project. 
I'm using OSX and I installed pip, python and downloaded pygame.

But I can't install it. I read my console log but I don't know how to fix it:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/e6/a0e790157db7dc6b62192d09a93085bcb2a5261ee45ddc4d6d225ecc4a4d/pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl
  Saved ./pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl
Successfully downloaded pygame
choehyomin-ui-MacBookPro:~ choihyomin$ pip install pygame
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/e6/a0e790157db7dc6b62192d09a93085bcb2a5261ee45ddc4d6d225ecc4a4d/pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl
Installing collected packages: pygame
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: Permission denied. try `sudo pip` instead of `pip`

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pygame'

Comment: still not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install -r: OSError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512422/pip-install-r-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Errno+13+Permission+denied

Comment: @Blorgbeard Please don't suggest using "sudo pip" -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/1931274

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a virtual environment so that you can install into that instead of your global Python installation. But if that's not an option, then the suggestion in the error message makes sense: use `--user`:

```
pip install --user pygame
```

But do make sure that `pip` installs for the Python interpreter you have selected in VS Code and not some other installed copy of Python. If you're not sure, the safest way is to specify the Python interpreter you want to install for:

```
/path/to/python -m pip install --user pygame
```