# Why numpy doesn't appear in my pip3 list within my virtualenv, even though I installed it doing pip3 install numpy two seconds before?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv. Then I proceeded to activate it.
Once activated, I installed numpy through `sudo pip3 install numpy`.

Once finished installing, I did `pip3 list` and numpy was not in the list.

Why?

Comment: Don't use `sudo`! This is a severe security threat. If you activated the virtual environment `pip3 install numpy` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: do *not* use `sudo pip3` but `pip3`. In fact *never* use `sudo pip3`.

If you want to use the `pip` of the virtual environment, you should *not* use `sudo`. In fact by using `sudo`, you bypass the virtual environment, and you will install the package system-wide, since `sudo` gets as argument `pip3`, and the virtual environment is not capable of "injecting" the local `pip3`.

You thus should simply run this as:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Besides not installing it in the local environment, using `sudo pip3` is a *serious* security threat. It means that you will run `setup.py` as a root user, and thus a malicious package can damage your system. See [*What are the risks of running `sudo pip`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip) for more information.