# How dangerous is using sudo pip?

Tags: python, security, beautifulsoup

I am very new to coding in general but wanted to learn web scraping for the upcoming NFL season so beautifulsoup was necessary to download. To install it, I inputed

sudo pip install bs4

in my terminal as instructed by this video here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVfhWr2ayKQ&ab_channel=OfficialJLara

After reading up a little on it, it seems to be the general consensus to not use sudo pip as it gives malicious files easy access to my computer. Did I do something tragically wrong here or is bs4 generally safe to download, even with using sudo pip? Sorry for being such a novice.

Comment: You should either install into a virtual environment, or if you want to install system-wide then use your operating system's package manager if a suitably packaged version is available. What exactly is your OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip)

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that it gives malicious files access to your computer (which, sure, it could), but also that you've just replaced the packaged version of `bs4` and potentially *any of its dependencies* with versions from `pip`. This could lead to system commands breaking if (a) they are based on Python and (b) they are incompatible with the updated version of a module installed by `pip`.

It's best to never use `pip` to install system-wide packages. You should either operate in your own account (`pip install --user ...`) or install things into a virtual environment specific to your project.

Comment: thank you for answering, I will definitely avoid using it from now on. Do you happen to know if bs4 is generally a safe way to download beautifulsoup?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. `bs4` is the name of the package that provides the `BeautifulSoup` class. You need to install that package if you want to use beautiful soup.

Answer (score 0):

The answers in this question are good: [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip)

You should just uninstall it and reinstall it without using sudo if you're concerned.

Comment: ya and then you can do `pip show bs4` to see if it's gone or `pip freeze` to see what you have installed