# Pyinstaller Cannot find xlrd

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, xlwt

I am running Python 3.5.1 and PyInstaller 3.2 on Windows.

I need to compile my script into an exe. I have done this with pyintaller before with different scripts and have had no issues. Pyinstaller is having trouble importing xlrd. I have tried:

```
--hidden-import=xlrd
```

and also

```
 --hidden-import xlrd and neither has worked.
```

I have heard about hooks but I cannot find any documentation on how to set up the hook-xlrd.py file.

I have been getting the error:

> ImportError: No Module called xlwt

The script runs perfectly from the Command Prompt.

Comment: Try this : sudo pip install xlrd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xlrd import issue with Python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407469/xlrd-import-issue-with-python-2-7)

Comment: Python **5.3.1**? What year do you live in?

Comment: @froost1999    The script runs perfectly from the command prompt. It is only when I try to run the .pyc file that I run into issues

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, your application requires `xlwt`. So do a `pip install xlwt` and then add `--hidden-import=xlwt` to your arguments. 
 For a more comprehensive guide, see [here](https://developpaper.com/packaging-python-as-exe-executable-pyinstaller-tool/).