# can not install pip on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, pip

When trying to install pip on an Ubuntu 12.04 VM using the [official method](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) it gives me the below error. I can not use the apt-get install python-pip as it installs pip 1.0

I removed my existing old copy of pip using the command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-pip
```

I then downloaded the get-pip.py file and used the below command to run it

```
 sudo python get-pip.py
```

But I get this error

```
 Downloading/unpacking pip
    Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
    Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
  Cleaning up...
  No distributions at all found for pip
  Storing debug log for failure in /home/xuyu/.pip/pip.log
```

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Setup

- Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Try doing this.. maybe the get-pip.py script didn't download correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17601159/2591612