# python cron job error in centos 6.3

Tags: python, linux, cron, centos6

i am running scrapy 0.24.4 and it need python2.7.
so i install python2.7 in /usr/local/bin/

and create name.sh file to run my script:

> > > cd /home/user/public_html/dir/
> > >       PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
> > >       export PATH
> > >       scrapy crawl script-call

and set crontab :

```
* * * * * /root/name.sh
```

**but it gives me output :**

```
Scrapy 0.24.4 requires Python 2.7
```

Comment: How was scrapy installed? You need to use your python2.7 executable when installing scrapy.

Comment: after python installation i run :pip install Scrapy.

Comment: my output : root@server [~]# which python>>
/usr/local/bin/python ;;root@server [~]# python -V >>
Python 2.7.6

Comment: Each pip executable is linked to a particular installation of python. So was your pip installed using your new python2.7 installation? If not, you need to [install a new pip using your python2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5585875/190597), and then use *that* pip to install scrapy.

Answer (score 1):

Order is significant. In order to pick your desired python, instead of:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
```

have:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
```