# How to install Pisa on Ubuntu

Tags: python, html, pdf, python-imaging-library

How can i install Pisa on Ubuntu?

http://xhtml2pdf.appspot.com/static/pisa-en.html

What is the best way to install it ?

Comment: Isn't `pisa` an abandoned project, whose docs tell you to install [`xhtml2pdf`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xhtml2pdf) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pisa`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa) is an abandoned project. The very first line of its entry says:

> **PLEASE SWITCH TO THE MORE RECENT VERSION AT: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xhtml2pdf**

If you really want to use the obsolete `pisa`, you can. You linked to the install docs, which show you exactly what to do.

Unlike `pisa`, `xhtml2pdf` is designed to install using `pip`, and the requirements are set up properly (in particular, using Pillow, which can be pulled in automatically, instead of PIL, which often doesn't work), so all you have to do is:

```
pip install xhtml2pdf
```

This will automatically pull in all of `html5lib`, `pyPdf2`, `Pillow`, `reportlab`, and `six` if you don't already have them, then install `xhtml2pdf`, and then you're done.

If you don't already have `pip`, [install it first](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html).

On *nix, if you're not using a virtualenv, user site-packages, or group-writable site-packages, you will of course need `sudo pip install xhtml2pdf` instead. (But you really should consider using a `virtualenv` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have pip, if you dont: [What is the official "preferred" way to install pip and virtualenv systemwide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585875/what-is-the-official-preferred-way-to-install-pip-and-virtualenv-systemwide)

First you will need to install the requirements:

**ReportlabToolkit 2.1+**

you will need to download mercurial for cloning the repository:
sudo apt-get install mercurial

then clone the repository:
hg clone https://your-user@bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab

```
cd reportlab/
python setup.py install
```

**html5lib 0.10+**

Look for the latest http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/ download, download it manually or:

```
curl -O [latest]
ex: curl -O https://html5lib.googlecode.com/files/html5lib-0.95.tar.gz

tar -xvzf [downloaded archieve]
ex: tar -xvzf html5lib-0.95.tar.gz 

cd [extracted folder]
ex: cd html5lib-0.95/
```

then:

```
python setup.py install
```

**PIL 1.1.6+ (optional)**

```
pip install Pillow
```

**pyPdf 1.11+ (optional)**
Will be used if you like to place another PDF as a watermark in the background of PDF pages
get the latest package at https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/

```
curl -O http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz
tar -xvzf pyPdf-1.13.tar.gz
cd pyPdf-1.13/
python setup.py install
```

Finally:

get pisa package link at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa

```
curl -O [pisa package link]
ex: curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pisa/pisa-3.0.33.tar.gz#md5=e2040b12211303d065bc4ae2470d2700

tar -xvzf pisa-3.0.33.tar.gz#md5=e2040b12211303d065bc4ae2470d2700 

cd pisa-3.0.33/

python setup.py install
```

That´s it

*Obs: Sometimes pip commands needs sudo.

Comment: This leaves off without telling you how to actually install `pisa` itself, it just has the "first the requirements" part.