# importing pandas error with jupyter notebook on windows 10

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So I deleted and reinstalled the most up to date version of Anaconda Navigator with Python 3.6 on Windows 10. I launched Jupyter notebook and tried to import

1, numpy,

2, matplotlib

and 3, pandas

It was able to import Numpy and Matplotlib but for Pandas it gave me a very long error message as follows. I also use a Mac computer and it seems no problem with importing pandas using the Jupyter Notebook.

[image: importing pandas error message]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/33482843/4175515

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481974/importerror-no-module-named-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

from the error message it seems that Pandas is not on of the pre-installed libraries in the Anaconda that you installed. It is the not the problem with the OS. Run the following command:

conda install -c anaconda pandas

then run the import statement.