# Importing pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, python-idle

I am new to Python and I am trying to `import pandas` but I'm getting

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'"

How can I fix this? I tried on both Python 3.8 and 3.7 and they're giving me the same error. I have Anaconda installed and I'm pretty sure pandas come with it? I have also tried `pip install pandas` and it gives me

> "Requirement already satisfied"

Please help me!!

Update: I just got mad and deleted Anaconda. I found another way to use pandas which is by doing pip install pandas in cmd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481974/importerror-no-module-named-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple instances of Python you likely have Pandas associated with another installation of Python. Please see the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/index.html) for installation and set-up. You can use [sys.executable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to see which instance of Python you are currently running.

Following the answer provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25907213/5225577) you can try `which python` to see which one you are using as well. This answer includes a solution of how to update your path to the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

use `python -m pip install pandas` this will install the pandas with the python environment you are running your code.

one done, you can do run your program using `python <program>.py`

it is better if you maintain different python version in separate virtual environments