# Installing Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and python as the language. I am trying to convert an XLSX file to pdf and I came across this question with answer. [Python - Converting XLSX to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326782/python-converting-xlsx-to-pdf).

One of the answer requires me to install pandas and also wkhtmltopdf and use them to convert the files into pdf format.

I tried installing pandas but after installing pandas, I am face with builtins.ImportError: No module named 'pandas'.

So far I have tried this solution but it did not work for me.

[ImportError: No module named pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481974/importerror-no-module-named-pandas)

Is it possible for me not to also install Anaconda to help me.

Can someone guide me through this.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install pandas? did it result in any error? are you in virtual env?

Comment: I installed panda using pip install pandas. I have tried using pip3 install pandas but I was met with this error Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zj48c0_y/pandas/. Yes i am in a virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PyCharm IDE, you can try:
Settings => Project Interpreter => plus button => search package to install

Comment: How about just running the script from the terminal?

Comment: I'm not sure about the script because I had the same problem and changing settings in IDE helped me