# Python 3: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.util' (raspberry pi)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Am having issues importing pandas on python3 on my raspberry pi. Whatever I try, I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.util'
```

It works fine on Python 2.7. I am getting errors with Python 3.7.3.

I searched Google and tried everything in the following post:

[ImportError: No module named pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481974/importerror-no-module-named-pandas)

Some of the things I’ve tried are below - none have helped - I still get the error.

```
pip3 install pandas-util
pip3 install pandas.util
sudo apt-get install python3-wheel
sudo python3 -m pip install pandas
pip3 install pandas --upgrade
```

I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy and pandas - still get this error just with a basic import statement.

Any help would be appreciated as this is driving me insane!!

Cheers!

Comment: I did an uninstall and then tried to install from scratch. If I try an upgrade, I just get "Requirement already satisfied" for all the elements.

Comment: Thanks! Using the --force-reinstall above worked! I'm knew to this - how do I make your answer the definitive one and give you credit?

Comment: I've added it as a proper answer. Thing is, for some of these problems, it's unclear what the issue is, and the answer is a bit of a guess (from experience). But without knowing the actual result, it's a "try, fail, re-try" cycle I usually keep in the comments (until it's hopefully fixed).

Comment: Great. Thanks again. Tried to upvote your answer but says I need more credits to do that! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall pandas
```

This will ensure two things:

- it will use the pip executable that belongs to the used Python executable, so that there is no accidental installation by another pip.
- it will properly re-install Pandas.

Note that it doesn't re-download the Pandas package (it will use a cached version) if the version on PyPI hasn't changed between now and the previous installation. If that is a potential problem (incorrect cached file, for example), add the option `--no-cache-dir` to `pip install`.