# Pip doesn't work on Mac OS X / ImportError: No module named utils

Tags: python, macos, pip

I can't get pip to work on OS X. I've tried everything I could find here, installing, removing, reinstalling python, etc. but nothing works. I keep getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Comment: can you look at the folder `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/` and see if there is a `utils.py` file in it?

Comment: There is no `utils.py` there - is there a way to reinstall and ensure it will be there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585875/what-is-the-official-preferred-way-to-install-pip-and-virtualenv-systemwide

Comment: sorry, meant to link to [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: Thanks - when I try installing, I get `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg`. And there is still no `utils.py` in that folder.Would a clean uninstall/reinstall work, and how is that done?

Comment: You can use the flags pip normally uses so try: `get-pip --force --upgrade --no-cache-dir`